# Is there a function equivalent to "String.IndexOf(String[])"?

Tags: c#

Is there any function that returns the index of the first occurrence of ANY string in a given array like: `String.IndexOf(String[])`?

or do I need a custom function for it?

For example the below function

```
 "AppleBananaCherry".IndexOf(new[] {"Banana", "Cherry"});
```

and

```
 "AppleBananaCherry".IndexOf(new[] {"Cherry", "Banana"});
```

returns 5

Answer (score 2):

There is no prepared function but you can use something like this,

```
var sample = "AppleBananaCherry";
var input = new[] { "Cherry", "Banana" };
var result = input.Min(x => sample.IndexOf(x));
```

> If sample has not any item of input, it returns -1

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for that, [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) method accepts only single string or `char` as parameter, but you can write your own extension method, which uses `IndexOf` for every item in array, like in the following sample. It also should correctly exclude `-1` from intermediate result

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static int IndexOf(this string thisString, string[] values)
    {
        var index = thisString.Length;
        var isFound = false;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            var itemIndex = thisString.IndexOf(item, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
            if (itemIndex != -1 && itemIndex < index)
            {
                index = itemIndex;
                isFound = true;
            }
        }

        return isFound ? index : -1;
    }
}
```

The usage example

```cs
var index = "AppleBananaCherry".IndexOf(new[] {"Banana", "Cherry"}); //returns 5
index = "AppleBananaCherry".IndexOf(new[] { "Cherry", "Banana" }); //returns 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is the result same for  new[] {"Banana", "Cherry"} ,and new[] {"Cherry", "Banana"} ? there should be a check for the smallest value but that makes the function very slow, so would a letter by letter comparing function be better?

Comment: You can run the code and check it. The result is 11, are you expect 5 there? Do you need an occurrence of any string from array?

Comment: yes I need the first index of any string in the array

Comment: @JhonDoe  I've updated an answer, please have a look. The code also properly checks the situation, when there is no items from array present in input string. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

This should

```cs
public static int IndexOf(this string s, string[] values) {
    var found = values
        .Select(v => s.IndexOf(v))
        .Where(index => index >= 0)
        .OrderBy(v => v)
        .Take(1)
        .ToList();
    return found.Count > 0 ? found[0] : -1;
}
```

**EDIT:** Removing -1 values

Comment: You'll need to exclude -1 otherwise min will prefer not found to first index.

Comment: But wouldn't this be slower than checking letter-by-letter if I'm dealing with a very large string?

Comment: Edited to remove ```-1```. About speed, it would depend on the strings used. If you really need to, you could create some kind of optimized tree or join several strings by using regular expressions. Please include examples of the input strings if this is really necessary.